# FreeTextBox not working on Mac Safari 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)

Tags: asp.net, macos, safari, freetextbox

I have noticed that the pages which contain FreeTextBox are freezing when I click the submit button. (infact any button on the page).

Is there anything I can do to get around this problem without having to actually replace all my FTB controls with some other text editors?

I am using asp.net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you post your problem to the [FreeTextBox Forums](http://forums.freetextbox.com/).  I doubt many people here have intimate knowledge of FreeTextBox on Safari.

I suspect though, you have a JavaScript error/conflict.

Comment: Thanks Rick, it works fine on all the other browsers, infact even Safari 5.0.5(7533.21.1) on windows. Seems to be an issue only on Mac. Also since IE doesn't throw a javascript error, I am assuming the javascript is fine. I will post this on the FreeTextBox forums as suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax Control Toolkit TextEditor Extender, it is light weight, and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Bhargav, but I am trying to avoid replacing the editor unless theres no other way. Is there any way I can strip down the FTB to its most basic version ... so as to make it light weight?

Comment: but TextEditor Extender, is more powerful and give more functionality then FTB.. check in codeplex for this new features becasue FTB is Beta now..now not full.